# Installing module with cpan2dist blaims about missing module although it is available

Tags: cpan

i'd like to install some perl-modules with cpan2dist. Cpan2dist creates rpm's of perl-modules. I'd like to install Data-Dumper:

```
cpan2dist --format CPANPLUS::Dist::SUSE --verbose --buildprereq Data-Dumper .
Data-Dumper needs Test::More, which is installed:
cpan2dist ...
...
[MSG] 'perl-Test-Simple' is already installed (for Test::More)
...

Perl itself confirms it: 
vm58820-6:~ # perl -MTest::More -e 'print "$Test::More::VERSION\n"'
1.001003
```

But later on cpan2dist complains about an unsatisfied dependency:

```
error: Failed build dependencies:
        perl(Test::More) >= 0.98 is needed by perl-Data-Dumper-2.151-0.x86_64
[ERROR] unsatisfied builddeps!
```

Cpan2dist does not seem to be sure if Test::More is installed or not. But if it says Test::More is not installed, why doesn't it install the dependency ? The option --buildprereq should do that.

Thanks,
Bernd

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED

Hi,
i found it out by myself. It seems that cpan2dist looks for already installed packages using different ways: the message "perl-Test-Simple' is already installed (for Test::More)" comes from cpan -l or autobundle in cpan, i believe. But cpan2dist also ask the rpm database, when it checks the dependencies. And "Test::More" has been installed with CPAN or it was included in the original perl-Installation. So the module is available for perl, but, because it was not installed with rpm, rpm knows nothing about it.

Bernd